# Python logging doesn't log when running via cron

Tags: python

If I run my script manually I see `runlog.log` populated with messages. When i run the script via cron, there's no output in my log file BUT i do see it in `/var/spool/mail/root` so I know the script works.

```
file_handler = logging.FileHandler("runlog.log", "a")
file_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
file_handler.setFormatter(default_formatter)

logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
logger.addHandler(file_handler)

...
logger.info("No new files")
```

Comment: You might try with an absolute path for the logfile.. Cron probably runs your script with the current directory set to `~root` (or `~user` , depending on who you run it as) and your logfile will end up where ever cron sets  the working directory to.

Comment: damnit, there it is! Thx